# Clear dropdownlist with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this little function to fill a drop down list with data from the server.

```
function fillDropDown(url, dropdown) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        // Clear drop down list
        $(dropdown).find("option").remove(); <<<<<< Issue here
        // Fill drop down list with new data
        $(data).each(function () {
            // Create option
            var $option = $("<option />");
            // Add value and text to option
            $option.attr("value", this.value).text(this.text);
            // Add option to drop down list
            $(dropdown).append($option);
        });
    });
}
```

I can then call the function in this way:

```
fillDropDown("/someurl/getdata", $("#dropdownbox1"))
```

Everything is working perfectly, except for the one line where I'm clearing old data from the drop down list. What am I doing wrong?

Any tips that might help to improve this code are also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Just use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
// snip...
}).done(function (data) {
    // Clear drop down list
    $(dropdown).empty(); // <<<<<< No more issue here
    // Fill drop down list with new data
    $(data).each(function () {
        // snip...
```

---

There's also [a more concise way](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) to build up the options:

```
// snip...
$(data).each(function () {
    $("<option />", {
        val: this.value,
        text: this.text
    }).appendTo(dropdown);
});
```

Comment: BTW, this would work quite nicely as a jQuery plugin with a little refactoring.

Comment: for me data was not a DOM list but a javascript array so instead `$(data).each(function () ...` -> `$.each(data, function()..`

Comment: I had to capitalize `Value` and `Text`

Answer (score 22):

I tried both `.empty()` as well as `.remove()` for my dropdown and both were slow. Since I had almost 4,000 options there.

I used `.html("")` which is much faster in my condition.
Which is below

```
  $(dropdown).html("");
```

Comment: 4000 options is probably too many for a user operable web page. Many browsers will have issues even rendering that. Consider a paged list or autocomplete/suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="ddlvalue" name="ddlvaluename">
<option value='0' disabled selected>Select Value</option>
<option value='1' >Value 1</option>
<option value='2' >Value 2</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="btn_submit" value="click me"/>



<script>
$('#btn_submit').on('click',function(){
      $('#ddlvalue').val(0);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the new `options` in a `variable`, and then using `.html(variable)` to replace the data in the `container`?