# How to order list items with a drop down menu in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to order a simple list of items using PHP. This should be done using a drop down menu that can select the criteria to order it by in ascending order. I'm quite stuck at the moment, I've created the form but I'm unsure what to do next. Apologies in advance but I have very little experience working with PHP.
I'm also unsure if the form needs to be placed in a particular location.

Thank you very much for the help in advance, I have an assignment deadline today!! :P

**The Tabular Data**

```
<?php
            try{
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=CU4199199','CU4199199','tehyajae15');
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
    $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM FILM WHERE GENRE_ID = 2');
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
    ?>
    <?php
    echo '<table class="listtables" border="0">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="125" rowspan="2">';
    echo '<a href="'.$row ['FILM_ID'].'.php">';
    ?>
    <img class="shadow" src="<?php echo $row['IMAGE_LINK']; ?>" width="125" height="125"> <?php 
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td>';

    echo '<td class="filmlisttitle">'; 
     echo '<h3><a href="'.$row ['FILM_ID'].'.php">'.$row['TITLE'].'</a></h3>';
    echo ' ('; 
    echo $row['RELEASE_YEAR'];          
    echo ')'; 
    echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="filmlistinfo">'; echo $row['SHORT_DESCRIPTION']; echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>'; 
    }

    $conn = null; ?>
```

**The Form**

```
<form name="sort" action="" method="post">
<select name="order">
   <option value="choose">Make A Selection</option>
   <option value="TITLE">TITLE</option>
   <option value="RELEASE_YEAR">RELEASE_YEAR</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value=" - Sort - " />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Order the list in the query. The options will be listed in the required order.

```
 $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM FILM WHERE GENRE_ID = 2 ORDER BY TITLE');
```

Comment: I'm unsure how I can cause the drop down list to rearrange the items though?

Comment: @user3183576. It should be sufficient to select the fields in the order you require. There is no way for the dropdown to do this. Then again, maybe I don't understand exactly what you require (did you provide all the details).

Comment: To be honest, it may not need to be a drop down list. However I do need a method of rearranging the list of items by the different criteria.

For example, order the films by RELEASE_YEAR or order them by TITLE.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried my solution, and what results are you getting? Is it working for you and if not why is it failing?

Comment: Yes,  it does work, but I would like the user to be able to reorder them with a click.

Comment: I see. Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327985/sort-dropdown-list