# Onclick of a button clear the populated drop-down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop-down list which gets populated dynamically . I have a button which has to clear the drop-down list whenever the user wishes to.

test.html

```
<select id="test">
<option></option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="refresh" />
```

here my select tag is populated dynamically. Once I click on the refresh button the populated values should be cleared. How do i proceed?

Comment: `$('#test').empty();` should do it. Didn't you google?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
$('#refresh').click(function(e)
{
    $('#test').empty();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Uee following

```
$('#refresh').click(function()
{
  $("#test").html("");
});
```

Means Expty HTML inside dropdown on click.

Check here Șhȇkhaṝ's answer .html("") is much faster than empty() .
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909326/clear-dropdownlist-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This will clear the drop down values:

```
document.getElementById(‘drpFruits’).options.length=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById('refresh').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';
});
```

No jQuery, clean native javascript code.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu8to0tj/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh");     
refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
document.getElementById("test").options.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide information about your answer. If you provide an answer people might have their problem solved, but if you tell them WHY they might actually learn something.